# Which USD token to recommend to friends?

Tags: token, trustline, history

I notice that both [USD/x.token.io](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset/USD-GDSRCV5VTM3U7Y3L6DFRP3PEGBNQMGOWSRTGSBWX6Z3H6C7JHRI4XFJP) and [USD/www.anchorusd.com](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset/USD-GDUKMGUGDZQK6YHYA5Z6AY2G4XDSZPSZ3SW5UN3ARVMO6QSRDWP5YLEX) have significant usage. I'm not sure what to tell friends looking to:

- convert XLM into USD tokens
- have a single USD trustline to accept (negating USD token splintering within wallets)

## Which would you recommend to your friends, and why?

Comment: My naive view: x.token.io metadata looks significantly more official & thought out, however it appears there's been <1% change in its supply. anchorusd historically shows large changes in supply, which to me indicates that it has at least a semi-functional withdrawal/deposit mechanism, but www.anchorusd.com is so less sexy-looking than x.token.io 

Comment: x.token.io does no longer exists.

Comment: Awws. Well, I suppose that settles that.

Answer (score 0):

Stronghold has the most volume on average.

Comment: Are you referring to [their USD token](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset/USD-GBSTRUSD7IRX73RQZBL3RQUH6KS3O4NYFY3QCALDLZD77XMZOPWAVTUK?filter=orderbook) which states "This asset has been retired. Please redeem this asset immeadiately" ..?

Comment: @wTyeRogers I thought they were a solid 3rd place contender until just now.

Comment: Yeah, for the life of me I can't figure out how to deal with their USDS (stronghold USD); I've successfully deposited 10 USD into their interface, however their site seems to not allow any method of utility with it aside from withdrawing. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯